# Odd behavior when pushing viewController from embedded navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Im sorry I don't have any real code for this but maybe I can give a helpful example.Let's say I have two VCs (#1 and #2) that consist of a full screen table view. In #1, I have enough cells to fill the entire view but #2 doesn't. When transition from #1 to #2 I see the bottom of #1 until #2 is fully in view.  I Have included a video to showcase example.

[image]

Comment: try adding "view.backgroundColor = .white" in your second view controller's viewDidLoad method

Comment: Do you modally present your VC2 with a custom animation? Or do you use the standard navigation push? With the standard navigation push you shouldn't have this visual bug. And when modally presenting you could use: modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen or .overFullScreen. And set the background color.

Answer (score 1):

**CalendarVC**

Use white background

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

**First VC**

Apple `clipToBounds` to Menu Images

Comment: yeah changing the view to white seems to have worked

Comment: makes no sense tbh

Comment: Did you use cliptoBounds ?

Comment: umm well the menu images are apart of a pagingcontroller so i might not need to do that

Comment: ill try it real quick though

Comment: You may try. It effects second Vc

Comment: hold on i have to try it with another view